# Skipping entire directory of unit tests in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following directory structure for my unit tests.

```
top/
    test1/
    test2/
    test3/
    ...
```

Each `test1` directory has an `__init__.py` that contains a class such as `TestSomething` that does the actual testing.

To temporarily disable these tests, I have to go through each `__init__.py` file and add the `@unittest.skip` decorator to the `TestSomething` classes.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures

As the number of tests has grown, this is becoming a tedious task because I have to go through each directory to disable the tests.

I am wondering if there's an easier way to disable all tests under a certain directory. For instance, is it possible to set something in `top/__init__.py` to turn off all tests in `top`?

Comment: How about move `top` directory outside the project directory temporarily, then restore when you're done ?

Comment: I would prefer not to move the top/ directory. Since all these directories/files are version controlled, I feel that that would lead to needless confusion.

Comment: How do you run the tests (which test runner do you use)? `python -m unittest discover`?

Comment: Well, I run nosetests from top/. I'm not sure if that is equivalent to `python -m unittest discover`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `unittest.skipIf(condition)` from your linked page will do what you want.

Add `unittest.skipIf(__skipThisDir__)` to each test in a directory, as well as an `import test_configuration` at the top of the file.

Then add a "test_configuration.py" to each directory which contains

```
 __skipThisDir__ = False  #or True as needed
```

Comment: That just seems to be a conditional way to skip individual tests. How/where can I use it to skip the entire directory of tests?